Trying to stop Spring batch job in before process but seeing below Exception
I am trying to stop the Spring batch job and below is the code.
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
     //Job stop changes start
    jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
    try {
        jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId());
    } catch (NoSuchJobExecutionException | JobExecutionNotRunningException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MDC.put(JOB_ID_KEY, jobId);
    blastManager.setJobStarted(jobId);
}

When I try to ran the code and seeing below Multiple Transaction Management Exception.Please help me to fix the exception.
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: omsTransactionManager,oracleTransactionManager,transactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)

Please help to fix multiple Transaction Management issue.

@Spring-data-jpa and spring-batch :- Any suggestions from any body
